# delayed_job waiting for completion

Tags: ruby, delayed-job

How can I poll for completion of a list of jobs with delayed_job?
The scenario is simple: I enqueue some root job, it does something and then enqueues a bunch of other jobs and I need to check if they all have completed.

Answer (score 0):

`delayed_job` has some hooks you can use [which are documented here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/delayed_job/2.1.4/frames). The `after(job )` hook seems the one that fits your needs.

When I had to implement remote api call I tried `delayed_job` and polling with `Faye` but I ended up using `resque` and `resque-status`, which use redis, it's the nicest way I know at present, but it's not exactly that similar to your situation.